# Case insensitive QueryExpression

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, case-insensitive, query-expressions

Is it possible to build a query with a ConditionExpression which is not case sensitive ?

```
ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression() 
{ 
  AttributeName = "lastname", 
  Operator = ConditionOperator.BeginsWith, 
  Values = new ObservableCollection<object>() { searchName } 
};
```

In this example I would like the search with searchName to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that this is a factor of the database collation that was chosen during install of CRM rather than a feature of QueryExpression.

The default during a clean install is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. You can check yours by executing the following sql statement:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('OrganisationName_MSCRM', 'Collation')
```

Comment: To clarify - if we assume that your current searches are case sensitive, then to achieve a case insensitive search you would need to change your database collation to use a case-insensitive collation. Though not just a case of clicking a button, this *is* possible and you should be able to readily Google it.

Answer (score -6):

you can find the correct answer at http://crmonaroll.blogspot.in/2013/06/case-in-sensitive-search-in-mscrm-2011.html

To do a case insensitive search in MSCRM 2011 we need to tweak the query a little bit ,for e.g.

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldname)) 
     query.Criteria.AddCondition("fieldname".ToLower(), ConditionOperator.Equal, fieldname.ToLower()); 
 EntityCollection col = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Here I am setting the schema name to `ToLower()` which actually does the trick, hope this help.Leave your comments.

Comment: For anyone else coming here from search engines, this does not work.

Comment: `"fieldname".ToLower()` simply returns `"fieldname"`. Maybe you thought it would enforce the `ToLower()` data-base side when it compared them? This does not work.