# Error when using tolower with OData REST API call: An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm, odata

As suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478141.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495905/odata-query-filter-conditions-and-case-sensitivity), I should be able to apply `tolower` to do a case-insensitive field match with a REST call to the `OrganizationData.svc` endpoint.

Here's my `GET` request:

```
/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet?$filter=tolower(EMailAddress1) eq 'me@awesome.com'
```

And I get the following result:

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>-2147220715</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">
    Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.
  </message>
</error>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I do a case-insensitive match on the `EmailAddress1` field on the `Contact` entity using the REST endpoint?

(Note: I know I can change the SQL Server collation to case-insensitive but I need this to work for Dynamics online as well).

---

**SOLUTION**

So it looks like `tolower` is not supported at all in the OData implementation for the Dynamics REST API. If you need to do a case-insensitive match, the only way I found is to change the SQL Server [database collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985610/case-insensitive-queryexpression) in an on-premise install.

For Dynamics online, you'd probably need to write a plugin that fires on entity create/update and converts the field to lower-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not be able to do that. By default all information (and in CRM Online) as well is stored in case-sensitive DBs so you just would not be able to do case insensitive search.

Comment: Please see the two "here" links in my question, which show examples of how this can be done.

Comment: You should recheck [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx). Tolower is not supported function for Odata usage in Microsoft CRM.

Comment: But why does it say so on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/using-filter-expressions-in-odata-uris and still I am getting the error `Error sending request: Not Implemented. Code: 0x0 Message:The "tolower" function isn't supported.`