# How to filter CRM records using FilterExpression and with case insensitivity?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, crm, query-expressions

I am working in a .NET project that requires creating QueryExpression to filter CRM records based on input client full name.

```
var query = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = Xrm.Contact.EntityLogicalName,
    ColumnSet = cols
};

query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)ContactState.Active);
query.Criteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;

var subfilter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or);
var conditionCheckFullNameEqualInput = new ConditionExpression("fullname", ConditionOperator.Equal, revenueEntity.ClientName);

subfilter.Conditions.Add(conditionCheckFullNameEqualInput);
var filterCheckInputContainedInFullName = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
Regex rgx0 = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
var tmparr0 = rgx0.Split(revenueEntity.ClientName).Where(s => !DataFeedProviderInputValidator.IsEmptyValue(s)).ToArray(); ;
foreach (var tmparritem in tmparr0)
    filterCheckInputContainedInFullName.AddCondition("fullname", ConditionOperator.Contains, tmparritem);//need to handle case-sensitive scenarios
subfilter.AddFilter(filterCheckInputContainedInFullName);

var filterCheckFullNameContainedInInput = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filterCheckFullNameContainedInInput.AddCondition("firstname", ConditionOperator.In, tmparr0);//need to handle case-sensitive scenarios
filterCheckFullNameContainedInInput.AddCondition("lastname", ConditionOperator.In, tmparr0);//need to handle case-sensitive scenarios
subfilter.AddFilter(filterCheckFullNameContainedInInput);

query.Criteria.Filters.Add(subfilter);
```

The problem with the code above is that if there is a contact with fullname like this "Fry, Paraskevi" on the CRM, it won't be matched if my input is something like this "FRY PARASKEVI". But if my input is "Fry Paraskevi" or "Paraskevi Fry", it will be matched perfectly. There are several records that are like that.

My question is, does FilterExpression support filtering CRM records with case insensitivity (like String.IndexOf or String.Equals)? What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive QueryExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985610/case-insensitive-queryexpression)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `ConditionOperator.Like`, use it like this:

```
filterCheckInputContainedInFullName.AddCondition("fullname", ConditionOperator.Like, "%" + tmparritem);
```

Update:

This seems to be more of a SQL Database collation stuff which decides the case sensitivity rather than CRM SDK itself.

Maybe you have to store case insensitive (upper or lower case equivalent) field value in another attribute which you can use as a [workaround](http://microsoft.public.crm.developer.narkive.com/Yx6aquKn/case-insensitive-queryexpression) to filter.

Comment: I did similar thing too (I put "%" in both sides of a string) but that couldn't solve the problem.