# Ignore Casing in dynamics CRM FetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I am using the below FetchXML

```
 <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="emailaddress" operator="eq" value="jon@gmail.com" />
    </filter>
```

So is there a way to ignore casing in Fetch XML?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10988415/7920473

Comment: Thanks @ArunVinoth I am looking for doing it with FetchXML

Comment: if you would have read the answer you can understand it’s more of a SQL settings

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to specify collation within a FetchXML query the way that you would in SQL. To build on the answer Arun linked you to, it is also possible to set database collation properties at the column level within SQL server.

Comment: As far as I know, D365 defaults to a case insensitive collation for  North American orgs using American English. What region are you in? Have you found an example where the casing of a value in D365 caused you to get different results than you wanted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive QueryExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985610/case-insensitive-queryexpression)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on sql server Database Settings. Default is case insensitive.

Although it’s optional, consider accepting the SQL Server default settings for Collation Designator, Sort Order, and SQL Collation. Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement supports the following collation orders:

> - Case-sensitive
> - Case-insensitive
> - Accent-sensitive
> - Accent-insensitive
> - Binary sort order (such as Latin1_General_100_BIN)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/on-premises/sql-server-requirements-recommendations